# Express integral as Γ function

Tags: integration

I have the following integral:
$$\int_0^\infty n^x e^{-wn}   \cdot dn$$

I have set  $$ z = w n $$

and came up with the following:
$$ \frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{w^{x+1}}   $$

It does not look very correct, but I am not sure what steps I missed.

Comment: I think this is correct for $w>0$.

Comment: "It does not look very correct..." but what if it were? :-)

Comment: (Also, why do people use $dn$? $n$ usually refers to a discrete variable $\ddot\frown$)

Comment: Then I pleasantly surprised myself :) :) I, also, apologize for using n. I am not a math major so was not aware of this convention. Sorry